# #import "PhoneGapDelegate.h" error message in phonegap?

Tags: iphone, cordova

Am very new to iPhone development and also am looking to work with PhoneGap Framework to create iPhone apps. I have created HTML, JavaScript in my PhoneGap project. I have imported those files in my project. When i compile my project the XCode shows the below error,

'`PhoneGapDelegate.h`' file not found

I have searched google to solve this error, but i can't find any single ideas from there. And also am very fresher in development. I have found this below link from google search i don't know how to use this in my project,

http://ldt.stanford.edu/~educ39109/yaac/lab3/iphone/Classes/PhoneGapDelegate.h

In project i don't have any PhoneGap Framework. And I have downloaded the sample app from PhonGap site.

Could you please help me to solve this issue and run the project?

Answer (score 0):

Did you say it was inside a framework? You may need to do something on the lines of

`#import <PhoneGap/PhoneGapDelegate.h>`